# Panels/Buttons and repainting headache

Tags: java, swing, repaint

As a coursework piece for school, we had to come up with a self-defined project, which I chose a game idea I was originally going to write on actionscript but decided to push for it on Java. This was initially going well, with the game code working, the sprite animations were being handled fine and everything was being maintained within a game loop. That was until i began to try and add components such as buttons and labels to it.

Currently the structure of my game is as this(   GameSystem[handles loop and redrawing] -- GameMenu [Simple intro screen with start game ] <---swaps between ---> GameContainer [holds information about the game]    )

My loop inside the GameSystem updates all necessary objects, repaints and then tells all the objects to repaint after.

Game System:

```
/**/for(int i = 0; i < UpdateList.size();i++){
/**/UpdateList.get(i).Update(delta * 1.1); // tell list the element is an object that extends an interface      
/**/}
/**/Game.repaint();

/**/@Override
/**/public void paint(Graphics g) {
/**/super.paint(g);
/**/Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
/**/g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
/**/        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
/**/for(int i = 0; i < UpdateList.size();i++){
/**/UpdateList.get(i).paint(g2d); // tell list the element is an object that extends an interface       
/**/}
/**/}
```

This is where it starts getting iffy, because the game system repaints it's self each loop, clearing the frame of previous stuff, the buttons which I add in my gamemenu which is created inside the game system get cleared and only reappear briefly when you mouse over them.

Game Menu:

```
    //////////////////
    // Start Button //
    //////////////////
    Buttons = new JPanel();     
    Buttons.add(Start_game = new JButton("Start Game"));
    this.add(Buttons);
    Start_game.addActionListener(new Load());
    /**/}
    ///////////////////

    //////////////////
    //Paint sprite //
    //////////////////
    @Override
    /**/public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    /**///super.paintComponent(g);
    /**/Buttons.paintComponents(g);
    /**/}
    ////////////////////////////////////
```

At this point I've tried paint, paint component, revalidate() and a variety of other stuff I've gleamed from other posts but none have helped. The only way I've had the button appear visible is if I remove the call to repaint in the game loop. However this then impacts the game as none of the objects are repainted.

TL DR: How can I Handle repainting the various objects in my update list and refreshing the Gamesystem panel without making any components such buttons disappear? Sorry if this is a noobish question but this is my actual first time working with Java as I wanted to expand outwards from actionscript, if any more info is required i will gladly add to the post, thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are extending `JFrame` and overriding the `paint(..)` method?  If so, don't do either.  Extend `JPanel` for the custom painting, override `paintComponent(..)` instead of paint, and return a preferred size as needed for that component.

Comment: Sorry about that forgot the question mark that does make sense seeing as im asking one. also on the case of JFrames, i was originally extending them until issues arose and i swapped them so if a class needs to call paint() it now extends a JPanel instead

Comment: `TL DR: How can I Handle repainting the various objects in my update list and refreshing the Gamesystem panel without making any components such buttons disappear.` is your question

Comment: yeah, that was a major brain fart on my behalf, thanks for editing it

Comment: ..is there any chance we will see an ***SSCCE*** any time soon?

Comment: just reading about them from the link you posted as i haven't heard of the term before

Comment: Trying to make an sscce for you but, it may be to difficult for me at my low understanding of it to shorten the code down to a manageable level just to extract the issue, i could post the zip-file with the sections commented, otherwise i think my incapability will just infuriate you, waiting for me to get it done.

Comment: *"i could post the zip-file with the sections commented"*  You'd also have to post 'enormous bags of cash' in order to get me to debug a Zip file of code for you.  Prepare an SSCCE if you want my help.

Comment: Was Able to find a remedy to my solution, the parent class that the menu was extending had a paintcomponent method in which while blank, was clashing. by removing all notions of that, the repaint no longer causes issues, all i have to do now is sort the layout which i can handle. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to handle the painting of the buttons differently than the painting of your game.

```
Game System
{
    paint loop
    {
        painting Game
    }
}

Components //managing the painting itself through paintComponent, trying to run at same time as Game System.
{
    paintComponent
}
```

So in effect, you are wanting to switch one to the other. You could either use `paintComponent()` in the `GameSystem` instead of `paint()`, which manages disposing of the graphics and repainting for you (if it is already extending a jComponent)...

or you need to start managing the buttons' painting similar to how you do it for your game, instead of relying on `paintComponent()`

Comment: Effectively then, in my game loop which calls the repaint, and then goes through the update list to repaint them, i would want a separate list of all the buttons and handle them the same as well?

Comment: It would be most recommended to let Swing handle the repainting through paintComponent since you are using Swing components, but if you are almost there and just need it working that should do it.